# When can infinite regular graphs be embedded in the plane?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry

An infinite $r$-regular graph is a graph with $\infty$ vertices where each vertex touches precisely $r$ edges.

We say an $r$-regular graph can be embedded in the $R^2$ Euclidean plane if its set of edges and vertices can be represented as a set of points on the plane where each point is connected via an edge to precisely the $r$ closest points to it. For example, some $4$-regular graphs can be embedded in the plane by placing each vertex of the graph on a unique point $(m,n)$ on the plane where $m$ and $n$ are integers. Some $8$-regular graphs can be embedded using the same placement.

The question is: for what values of $r$ do there exist connected $r$-regular graphs that can be embedded in the plane?

The graphs need not be planar, but an answer dealing with the planar case is welcome.

Comment: So your question is: For which $r$ does there _exist_ an infinite $r$-regular graph that embeds in the plane in the way you have defined? (I'm pretty sure not _all_ 4-regular graphs will embed in that way).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'll clarify. Maybe the question should be asked differently: when is a placement of points on the plane an $r$-regular graph.

Comment: So, just to be clear (on another point), the graph does not need to be *planar*; it just has to be embedded in the plane such that each vertex is connected by an edge to its $r$ nearest neighbors?

Comment: I'm interested in both cases, but I don't strictly require the graphs to be planar.

Comment: Since you don't require connectedness, then the nonplanar case is trivial, as you can just take an infinite number of copies of $K_r$ and place them sufficiently far apart from each other.

Comment: I should've specified I do require connectedness. Thanks.

Comment: I think planarity implies connectedness when $r > 4$ by a coloring and average degree argument. (coloring by De Bruijn-Erdos, so AC is needed to make that claim)

Answer (score 4):

For every $r$ there exists a planar, connected $r$-regular graph, and here is an explicit construction:

Start with a vertex at $(1,0)$. Connect it to vertices $(i,1)$ for $i=1,2,...,r$. Now, draw vertices at $(i,2)$ for $i=1,...,r(r-1)$. Connect $(1,1)$ with $(1,2),...,(r-1,2)$. Connect $(2,1)$ with $(r,1),...,(2(r-1),1)$, etc.

Now draw vertices at $(i,3)$ for $i=1,...,r(r-1)^2$, and connect every vertex $(i,2)$ with $r-1$ of these. Continue like that.

It's easy to see that this construction will result with a connected, planar, $r$-regular tree.

Here is beginning of the construction for $r=3$:

[image]

Comment: Your vertices are not connected to "precisely to the $r$ closest vertices".